# Check for empty field

Tags: entities

I'm using the following method to check whether a variable is set before printing

```
if (isset($content['field_name'])):
print render($content['field_name']);
endif;
```

But when the field is empty, unknown is printed.

Is there a Drupal method for checking empty variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$content['field_name'] is always set.
You can check if it's empty.

```
if (isset($content['field_name']) && !empty($content['field_name']):
  print render($content['field_name']);
endif;
```

Comment: this code also renders "unknown"

Comment: Strange, where does $content['field_name'] come from?

Comment: Unknown was the actual field value..

Comment: Owkay nice to see it's working :-)